# Send image between apps

Tags: c#, image, api, base64, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET CORE API app and now I have an endpoint like:

```
[HttpPost("receipt")]
[ValidateModel]
[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(string))]
[SwaggerResponse(400, typeof(string))]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendReceipt([FromBody] EmailDetails emailDetails)
{
    try
    {
        var requestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        var connectionId = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>().ConnectionId;
        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(emailDetails, requestId, connectionId);
        return Ok($"The mail has been sent successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest($"Error sending email: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

While Model looks like:

```
public class EmailDetails
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Receipt { get; set; }
}
```

So for now as you can see I'm getting an image in Base64 encoded string and then I convert it to the image.

Is it a good idea to get an image in that way? Maybe should I use some alternative solution?

If you need any assistance, please let me know.

Comment: Is your code working and sending images as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I'm asking if is a good solution?